# Network connection on main thread - alternative in this case?

Tags: android, okhttp, networkonmainthread

I need to get a color in the server and set it as a theme

```
setTheme(colorId);
```

it needs to be set inside `onCreate()` and at the beginning to work.

I'm doing this:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getColor();
    ...
    }

public void getColor() {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX; //force network on main thread
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                            .url("http://myip/color.php")
                            .build();
                    try {
                        okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                        String color = response.body().string();
                        setTheme(color);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
    }
}
```

So, I'm forcing a network connection on main thread because if I add `doInBackground(), on response...` it will run after my `onCreate()` and the color will not be set.

My question here is:

1) Is it the only way?

2) Can I do things without force network on main thread?

3) I'd like an example, if possible, not just: "yes, it is possible" or "do XYZ" because I'm new to Android and without examples it doesn't help much.

Comment: try to make splash screen and get color from splash screen then start your main activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't make any network requests on the main thread.
Instead, you should show the user a progress bar whilst it fetches the data on a background thread.

**BUT**: Since you have to set the theme in the onCreate() it means you can't show the user any progress because the views won't be inflated at that point. A better solution would be to get the color from the server on a previous activity and pass it in as and intent parameter.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I thought about it, to get color and set by intent I'll try other things, but if they do not work I'll do this because it will be an irrelevant data that I get if user do not open the activity to set color. but is a good idea tho.

Comment: Yeah I think it's still better than giving the user a bad experience. If your server takes longer than 5 seconds to respond (which can easily happen if the user is on a poor/intermittent network) they will get an ANR screen.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html
If the color doesn't change often, you can also put some logic to get it once and save it to the shared prefs

Answer (score 1):

It's always a bad idea to force the network to the main thread

Replace the UI blocking call

```
client.newCall(request).execute();
```

With an asynchronous call

```
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
```

Check the documentation on how that all works

> if I add doInBackground, on response... it will run after my onCreate and the color will not be set

In an Asynctask? Then you're doing something wrong. Okhttp doesn't need an Asynctask

Comment: I noticed that you had Volley in other questions. You'll be have the exact same issues with Okhttp and the Callback

Comment: oh, yeah, in some activities I'm using volley and in others Okhttp... is it wrong?